# GEOGRAPHY field not working in one table working in another?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables with single GEOGRAPHY column which has WRT string for Polygon. Query on one table works well on other returns all rows instead of one.

A table with POLYGON in GEOGRAPHY column. When queried with ST_CONTAINS and single point returns ALL rows instead of single. If I convert field content to string and then back to GEO it works but VERY SLOW. I have another similar table where it works very fast on more records.

Query which returns all records:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM pur.sections WHERE ST_CONTAINS((POLYGON), ST_GEOGPOINT(-121.253763, 38.354874))
```

Query which works but slow - 23 seconds !:

```
SELECT polygon FROM pur.sections WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(ST_ASTEXT(POLYGON)), ST_GEOGPOINT(-121.253763, 38.354874))
```

Returns:

```
[
  {
    "polygon": "POLYGON((-121.241934066695 38.3649672043987, -121.241834795711 38.350891363934, -121.260351761597 38.3508607773966, -121.260367162138 38.3649633106378, -121.241934066695 38.3649672043987))"
  }
]
```

Table has 164K rows.

First query to return single row very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have a plausible explanation how this might happen. The issue is probably polygon origientation:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#polygon_orientation

If the data was loaded into the table from files, BigQuery assumed the polygons are oriented according to the rule described in this link:

> if you traverse the boundary of the polygon in the order of the input vertices, the interior of the polygon is on the left

Likely the polygons had wrong orientation, and thus BigQuery interpreted them as huge complimentary polygons, so now ST_Contains returns true most of the time.

In the second query, you print the polygon, and then call `ST_GEOGFROMTEXT` without `oriented` parameter, here BigQuery interprets WKT as describing the polygon with smaller area, so you get expected results.

You might fix the table (assuming all polygons are smaller than hemisphere, which is probably the case) by running:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE pur.sections AS 
SELECT * EXCEPT(POLYGON), ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(ST_ASTEXT(POLYGON)) AS POLYGON
FROM pur.sections
```

After which you should get expected result from simpler query.

Comment: Yes and yes ! I forgot to post it but after reading small print how WKT strings are interpreted by BigQuery I got the same idea and fixed it EXCATLY same way. Thanks anyway !